# Hybris OOTB ProductService can't find an existing product

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, flexible-search

I have several products registered in Backoffice, If I perform a flexible search query directly from HAC I can see any of them, however, If I use ProductService#getProductForCode that performs the same query as I do it doesn't find any products. How is that possible?

Comment: are the products synced to the online version of your product catalog?

Comment: yes, they are sync

Comment: how are you testing this service? the documentation specifies that only the catalog versions on the session will be used. As you tagged datahub, I assume you have no active catalog on your session when doing the search. Try to debug this with CatalogVersionService#getSessionCatalogVersions right before you fetch the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try disable search restriction before you call `productService#getProductForCode`

```
import de.hybris.platform.search.restriction.SearchRestrictionService;
......
searchRestrictionService.disableSearchRestrictions();
```